# A question about a case where Central Limit Theorem doesn't apply

Tags: probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, central-limit-theorem

I'm trying to read Lehmann's "Elements of Large Sample Theory" and I have the following question about the text.

The classical Central Limit Theorem is stated as:

[image: Statement of the central limit theorem]

Now, the author goes on to provide the following counter-example:

[image: Counterexample as described]

My question is, **what assumption of the CLT does this counter-example violate?** Could it be that in this case $\{X_i\}$ are not identically distributed, since they depend on $n$? Perhaps we do not have finite variance? But I checked and variance does look finite.

The author talks about the fact that the distribution F of $\{X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots, X_n\}$ depends on $n$ but that CLT assumes that this distribution $F$ (of any sequence where CLT applies) to be fixed. **Where exactly does CLT make this assumption as stated?** Or is the author just simply not giving a precise enough statement of CLT?

Please shed light, ye wise math stackexchange folk.

Comment: The CLT uses a single infinite sequence of iid variables. Your setup is really infinitely many finite sequences of iid variables, where each finite sequence uses a different distribution. That's how the sum can get away with being P(1) distributed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your explanation does make sense. This is a subtle (at least to me) difference.

Comment: I've also found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability)